# How can you detect if an image is present on the screen when it's in a stacked layer?

Tags: javascript

[image]

Consider the above the diagram, 3 layers stack on top on each other within the same container.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.layer1, .layer2, .layer3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.layer 1 {
  z-index: 3;
}

.layer 2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.layer 3 {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Let's assume each layer will be hidden after 2 seconds. So layer 1 will be invisible after 2 seconds, then layer 2 shows, then layers is hidden 2 seconds after, layer 3 shows.

There is an image on layer 3. And I want to do something with the image -- maybe apply some animation effects -- while it's showing.

In traditional layout, I can use a library like WOW.js to apply classes to an element when users scroll to that area. With an layout like this, I can't use WOW.js or the like.

How do I detect the image is "visible" on the screen so that I can do something with it?

---

edit:

I realized that the content in this question can affect the answer I want.
In my actual layout, each layout is revealed while users are scrolling the screen.

My actual layout is inspired from this:
http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/section_wipes_manual.html

while users is scrolling, each layer is being revealed.

Comment: How are you hiding your layers?

Comment: write the stuff in in the same function you use for hiding layers.

Comment: @karthick my actual layout is more complex than this, I use GSAP to manipulate an layout's translateY property when users scroll. So while an user is scrolling the screen, layer 1's y property is manipulated, after layer 1 is "invisible", manipulate layer 2's y property.

Comment: @JoshuaLeung It will be better if you can show a minimum example with the GSAP code.Tween libraries have onComplete event, see if you can leverage that someway. Are you using any GSAP compatible libraries like scrollmagic to manage your scroll?

Comment: @karthick I have updated my question.

Comment: if you have a scene then you can use the on "enter" event . if you don't have it then create a scene with proper trigger elements and pins. that should help you

Comment: @karthick great advice, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have `n` layers, and every 2 seconds one disappears. On the `n`th iteration, stop removing layers and do something with the final layer.

Using [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp), his could look something like:

```
let count = 0;
let timer = setTimeout(iterate, 2000);

function iterate() {
    if count < n // remove layer and iterate count (count++)
    else if count === n // stop timer and add desired effects
}
```

Comment: All said, it's not quite the same logic as "detect visible". There are some useful jQuery selectors that would help with that if you're not opposed to it.

Answer (score 0):

Take two: `scrollTop`. You'll find some relevant information/examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp), but in essence what you can do is reveal your elements as the user scrolls down the page. For example:

```
if(document.body.scrollTop > x) { /* do something */ }
```